# Странный вывод массива char

Tags: c++

Я использую

```
void func(char* m)
{
    for(int i = 0;i < 16;i++)
    {
        std::cout << (int)m[i] << std::endl;
    }

}

int main()
{
    char m[] = { 0x2b, 0x28, 0xab, 0x09,
                 0x7e, 0xae, 0xf7, 0xcf,
                 0x15, 0xd2, 0x15, 0x4f,
                 0x16, 0xa6, 0x88, 0x3c };
    func(*m);

}
```

Вывод получаеться такой

```
43
40
-85
9
126
-82
-9
-49
21
-46
21
79
22
-90
-120
60
```

Вопрос откуда взялись все эти отрицательные числа? Например вместо -85 должно быть 171 так как `0xab` в десятичной системе равна 171, тогда откуда -85?

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что у вас `char` - беззнаковый?

Comment: А где же "двумерный массив"?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Система_типов_Си

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В зависимости от типа и настроек компилятора тип `char` может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым.

Знаковые числа на всех популярных архитектура хранятся в [дополнительном коде](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4).

Беззнаковое 171 и знаковое -85 имеют одинаковое представление в памяти `0xAB` = `10101011b`

Ответ на прямой вопрос "Вопрос откуда взялись?" — вы их сами указали.

"Как исправить?" — явно использовать беззнаковый тип `unsigned char`

Могу ошибаться, но вроде бы, `char`, `signed char` и `unsigned char` — это три разных типа (в отличии, например от `int` и `signed int`, которые являются синонимами), и использовать просто `char` для числе не совсем корректно.

Comment: А в стандарте сказано, как именно хранятся отрицательные числа?...

Comment: @Harry, поправил ответ. Если склероз не изменяет, то дополнительный код указан только для дополнительных типов int8_t, int16_t и подобных.

Comment: @Harry, начиная с C++20, все целые в дополнительном коде.

Comment: @wololo Спасибо за информацию.